# Discouragement for new users

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, privileges, question-restrictions

**Why is the barrier for new users on Stack Overkflow or related sites this high?**

There are some "how to gain reputation points" posts, like "[6 Simple Tips to Get Stackoverflow Reputation Fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)" but those tips involve a declining quality of answers.

What would/could happen if the barriers for new user were lower as far as reputation points and the related restrictions are concerned?

Specification:

(1) This refers to restrictions, that I actually can't all call by name, because I am NEW!!! I am learning to use and contribute to the site and the community.

Found in the question: [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

"I think the point about wiki-editing is significant. If the barrier was much lower, we'd get better quality answers, and people would also be less keen to run around, scrabbling for rep. I think Jeff's reservations about this are slightly too great - wikipedia has proven to work without such draconian restrictions."  [image]

(2) Restrictions on politeness.

About the *tone*, found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79424/pouncing-on-newbies).

"Who knows if this new user will be one who contributes and asks better questions later? At this point they probably have a very bad impression of SO and its users.
Does anyone else think that the community needs to lighten up a little?"
[image]

I am working on specifiing the topic more.

Comment: Which barriers are you talking about? Most basic privileges are fairly easy to reach

Comment: Barrier for what? I don't understand exactly what problem you're talking about.

Comment: As it is this is really too vague to really answer.  You should probably choose a specific privilege, state what you think the rep limit should be, and explain why the site would be better off with this new rep limit rather than the current one.  If you think multiple privileges should change, each should really be in their own question.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting question, but it would be helpful if you could better explain the barriers that you are referring to.

Comment: Focus on one issue. And tell us what exactly you think the problem is (and what you propose to lessen that problem). Don't start to list 50 different things that might need tweaking.

Comment: And keep in mind that with regards to new users and tone, we have already had many discussions. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users for example. Also, please don't quote out of context. I don't want to have to dig around in another question to figure out what the background of a quote is. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Your first quote about wiki posts is pretty much meaningless.  The functionality surrounding them has changed quite a bit since then, so it's not really meaningful anymore.  You also still have no suggestion that you're making, and no specific problem that you're describing.  You're pretty much just saying, "Make it better!" which is rather unhelpful, by itself.